# Multiple clocks support in chisel iotesters

Tags: chisel

I am trying to develop my module which has multi clock domains with chisel3 and iotesters. But go through chisel wiki not found such documents and examples. such as how to set clock frequency, how to step...

Comment: Could you share some information about this ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no real support in chisel-testers for multi-clock. The API does not have any primitives for multi-clock. This is a recognized problem and there is a current development focus on fixing this.  See [RFC New Testers Proposal](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/issues/725). Comments are welcome. Chisel does allow multiple clocks, there just isn't support in chisel-testers. I'd suggest digging into [rocket-chip](https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip) a bit to see how it is tested there.